# getBaseContext() error for parsing data

Tags: java, android, error-handling

This code is for an attempt registation.class android studio application for parsing data.My code keeps giving me errors under my getBaseContext() code at the end and I have no idea why as I think it looks ok!!! the code is for a lab so it should be correct but i keep on getting errors!!!!

Can anybody tell me?? Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you

```
 public class AttemptRegistration extends
    AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

int success;
String message = " ";

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    try {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("tag", "register");
        params.put("username", args[0]);
        params.put("password", args[1]);
        params.put("email", args[2]);

        //
        HttpUtility.sendPostRequest(params);

        //


        String response = HttpUtility.readRespone();

        JSONObject jObj = null;

        try {

            jObj = new JSONObject(response);

            success = jObj.getInt("success");
            message = jObj.getString("message");


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data" + e.toString());
        }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        HttpUtility.disconnect();
        return message;

}
    protected void onPostExecute(String status) {

    if (status !=null) {

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if(success == 1) {
            startActivity (new Intent(getBaseContext(), LoginActivity.class));
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: `getBaseContext()` is not a method available to `AsyncTask`. If you need to show a Toast you will need to pass a reference to your Activity. If your AsyncTask is an inner class you can call `YourActivity.this.getBaseContext()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> .My code keeps giving me errors under my getBaseContext() code at the
>   end and I have no idea why as I think it looks ok!!!

[getBaseContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getBaseContext()) is a method of `ContextWrapper`. Since you are getting the `cannot resolve the method` error, it means that your `AsyncTask` class is not defined as inner class of a Class that inherits from `ContextWrapper` (`Activity` E.g). You could pass it the `Context` to your `AsyncTask` .

```
public class AttemptRegistration extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    private final Context mContext;
    public AttemptRegistration(Context context) {
       mContext = context;
    }
```

and then use `mContext` instead of `getBaseContext()`